# Learning c++ -- reading numbers from a file

Tags: c++

Quick synopsis: I can write the data into the file correctly (I've checked the .txt file and it presents exactly as it should) but all I can read back is the last number inputted. So, if the last quiz grade I input is 85, that's all it will read back. (the studentNumber reads back fine.) 
Thanks all! Still learning here ...

```
while (answer == 1)
{
   cout << "What is the student ID?\n";
   cin >> studentNumber;
   cout << "\n";
   cout << "How many quizzes did you take?\n";
   cin >> numQuiz;
   outputFile << "\n";
   outputFile << studentNumber << "\n";
   outputFile << "Number of quizzes: " << numQuiz << "\t" "Grades: ";
   for (int quiz = 1; quiz <= numQuiz; quiz++)

   {


      cout << "Please enter the score for quiz " << quiz << "\t";
      cin >> score;
      total += score;
      // cout << "The score is " << score << " .\n"; 
      outputFile <<  score << "\t"; }

   // outputFile <<  total; 
   cout << "Do you have a student's grades to input?\nIf yes, type 1. If no, type 0.\n";
   cin >> answer;
   cin.ignore();


}

outputFile.close(); 
fstream inputFile;



inputFile.open("grades2.txt");
inputFile >> studentNumber;
cout << studentNumber << "\n";

inputFile >> score;
cout << score << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong operator to read the data back. Instead of

```
inputFile << studentNumber;
```

you need to use

```
inputFile >> studentNumber;
```

Comment: I fixed that and the problem remains. Whatever I input as the last score in the loop is the only score it will read out. I need to be able to get all 3 (and eventually many more, as it were).